# How do I check to see if value exists within comma-separated field?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, csv

I'm working on designing a "friend" system for my site.  I have a USERS table in my database and two fields in that table called "friendrequestssent" and "friendrequestsreceived".

When a user sends a friend request to another user, it stores his USERID into the other person's "friendrequestsreceived" field and the other person's USERID into his "friendrequestssent" field, both with a trailing comma (ie: `12345,`).

I need to check to see if a request already exists in order to prevent duplicate requests, and so far I've tried this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = $userid AND $profileid IN (friendrequestssent);";
    $sent = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = $profileid AND $userid IN (friendrequestsreceived);";
    $received = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
    if(($sent > 0) && ($received > 0)) {
//do stuff here
}
```

This worked great at first, but when multiple comma-separated values exist in the field (ie: `12345,12346,`) , the IN statement no longer finds the value and the number of rows remains zero.

As far as I can tell, I cannot see why the IN statement in the MySQL query won't see the value.

On the other hand, I'm sure there is a far better way to do this anyway.  I'm just not sure how yet.  Please advise.

Comment: CSV in database is evil, it will send you straight to hell.

Comment: Isn't IN() type specific? i.e. you don't mix integers and strings and you're effectively passing an integer (the user id) to a string (csv) - it might be alright with just the one entry, if there's no comma it may be able to evaluate the string of numbers as an int. I'm not 100% certain though as I never use CSVs in the database - they just scream "this should be a link table" to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is OK, but it will be better if you let me redesign this for you:

First leave your table users as it is, then do a new table with 3 fields:

- An autoincrement field as your index (if you want it, or just skip this column).
- A field where you store a friend that is requesting a friendship and lets call: friend_request.
- A field where you store the friend that is receiving the friendship request, and lets call ir: friend_receive_request.

You should add the propper foreign key indexes and be aware that you could have duplicate requests by storing the same friendship in different columns. I could clear this more if you have questions.

Comment: Ah, yes I can see how a separate table for the friend requests could be more efficient.  I've done some reconfiguring and it's working wonderfully.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The IN clause looks at individual members of a comma-separated list, but when you store that comma-separated list in a single field, MySQL treats it as a single-string value, so you're doing

```
... WHERE x IN ('1,2,3')
```

which translates into

```
... WHERE x = '1,2,3'
```

To force MySQL to treat that CSV list as a CSV and not a monolithic string, you'll need the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
... WHERE FIND_IN_SET($profileid, friendrequestssent);
```

Comment: While creating a separate table for the friend requests was a much more efficient solution, your answer is still helpful in case I ever need to use something like `IN` again, and I'm sure I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't treat a single field like it's multiple rows. Use a table for this. Something like:

```
friend_requests
===============
friend_id
requested_friend_id
```

`friend_id` and `requested_friend_id` will comprise a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is fetch the entire entry containing all the id's in the form of an array or string and den appropriately do a string search or an array search to check for duplicacy.